# How do I add this C library to my iOS Xcode 4 project?

Tags: ios, c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying to add the openjpeg library to my XCode 4 project so that I can compress images taken by the iPhone's camera to jpeg2000.

I built the static library (libopenjpeg.a) using Cmake on OS/X. (I'm guessing this may have been the first error, that it needs to be built by XCode so it's built for iPhone architecture and not OS X).

I have the library added in the **Link Binary with Libraries** of my target.

The project builds successfully but I can't seem to import any of the headers from the library into any of my Objective-C classes. I've tried manually adding the folder that contains the libopenjpeg header files to the User Header Search Path but that did not seem to do anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

for the simplest solution

Import the head files to you project's source.

Answer (score 0):

You can still build it on the command-line with CMake, you'd just have to modify the CMakeLists.txt file so the right flags are passed when compiling.

However as Gavin indicates, it may be simpler just to drag the header and source files from the library into your Xcode project, and forego the building of a static library.